# Mariadb Columnstore: Version buffer overflow

Tags: mysql, mariadb, buffer-overflow, columnstore, infinidb

I am trying to add new data to a columnstore table, but it is returning this error:

`ERROR 1815 (HY000) at line 25: Internal error: CAL0001: Insert Failed:  IDB-2008: The version buffer overflowed. Increase VersionBufferFileSize or limit the rows to be processed.`

I already increased the `VersionBufferFileSize` value, but the problem still happens. I can't even create a new table using columnstore engine. When I try to run:

`create table x(a int) engine=columnstore`

I get this error:

`Internal error: CAL0009: (2)Create table failed due to  WE: Error updating calpontsys.systable:BRM block version buffer overflow error.`

When I look at the `versionbuffer.cdf` file in my data directories (4 pm nodes), some of them are with 1G size. I suppose that they reached the 1G limit in the `Columnstore.xml` file. Even if I increase the limit to 5G in the xml file, the versionbuffer.cdf size does not increase.

How to fix this problem? Is there a way to empty the versionbuffer file?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to stop the Database, rename the Version buffer and start it again. If it starts and creates the version buffer, you are done. If not, rename it back and things will work again.
just make sure that there are no transactions pending when stopping the system.

The version buffer is storing in-flight transactions to allow safe rollback activities. if there are no pending transcations, there should be no problem when renaming the buffer.

also note that the version buffer is allocated per dbroot - if you have more than one.

I have had the same problem in the past, i think it worked but im not 100% sure.